# Paging standard out using 'more', and piping to syslog

Tags: bash, scripts, pipe

I've implemented a wrapper script which causes all commands executed via this wrapper script to log (via rsyslog) things such as the execution time, the user that ran the command, and the exit code.

I am trying to implement paging and I have encountered a problem with the 'more' command. The root of my problem is that 'more' seems to quit when it is piped to another program, e.g.

```
echo -e "this\nis\na\ntest" | more -3 | cat
```

This will print 4 lines, though if we trim the '| cat' at the end, then it will pause after printing 3 lines, as expected.

Admittedly, using 'less' instead of 'more' does work, though this doesn't have the desired effect as it opens a seperate "window" and doesn't allow scroll back once it is completed (I don't need the ability to scroll backwards in the way that 'less' allows either).

My current solution is to use 'head' and 'tail' commands to get the effect I want, but there are some other challenges to face their as well.

Does anyone know the secret to make 'more' work in the way I envisioned? Suggestions for another paging tool that is simpler (supports Enter, space, and 'q' actions) are also welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using `tee` to redirect to a file and paging stdout would be more appropriate than paging in the middle of a pipeline:

```
printf "%s\n" this is a test | tee /tmp/some.file | more -3
```

Comment: That is a reasonable solution, however, since I am not piping the command directly (i.e. the output is being piped outside of this script) edit: That is to say it looks something like './my_script | logger'

Comment: Well: `logger() { tee /tmp/some.file | more -3; }`

Comment: Unfortunately the logger utility is how we write to the syslog, so tee is not an option for this problem. Sorry for not clarifying sooner.